# python ttp parser lookup and input

Tags: python, parsing, text

I'm stuck with TTD and creating a python script that would take configs from a file as a txt as an input and lookup all FW rules to human-readable lines.

I noticed that this would work and tested it at https://textfsm.nornir.tech/#

```
<input name="IP_data" load="text">
add IPAddress Name=SomeIP1 Address=1.1.1.1/24
add IPAddress Name=SomeIP2 Address=2.2.2.2/24
add IPAddress Name=SomeSubnet3 Address=3.3.3.0/24
add IPAddress Name=SomeSubnet4 Address=4.4.4.0/24
add IPAddress Name=SomeGW5 Address=5.5.5.5/24
add IPAddress Name=SomeGW6 Address=6.6.6.6/24
</input>

<input name="Services_data" load="text">
add ServiceTCPUDP Name=SomePorts1 Type=TCPUDP DestinationPorts="1, 11, 111"
add ServiceTCPUDP Name=SomePorts2 Type=TCPUDP DestinationPorts="2, 22, 222"
</input>

<input name="Rules_data" load="text">
add IPRule SourceInterface=if1 DestinationInterface=if1 SourceNetwork=SomeIP1 DestinationNetwork=SomeIP2 Service=SomePorts1 Action=Allow
add IPRule SourceInterface=if2 DestinationInterface=if1 SourceNetwork=SomeSubnet3 DestinationNetwork=SomeSubnet4 Service=SomePorts2 Action=Allow
</input>

<group name="IPAddress.{{ IPName }}">
add IPAddress Name={{ IPName | WORD }} Address={{ IP }}
</group>

<group name="Services.{{ PortName }}">
add ServiceTCPUDP Name={{ PortName | WORD }} Type={{ Protocol | default("Undefined") }} DestinationPorts={{ Ports | PHRASE | strip('"') }}
</group>

<group name="Rules">
add IPRule SourceInterface={{ SrcInterface }} DestinationInterface={{ DstInterface }} SourceNetwork={{ SourceNetwork | WORD | lookup(group="IPAddress", add_field="SourceNetwork") }} DestinationNetwork={{ DestinationNetwork | WORD | lookup(group="IPAddress", add_field="DestinationNetwork") }} Service={{ Ports | WORD | lookup(group="Services", add_field="Ports") }} Action={{ Action }}
</group>
```

Is there any better way of doing it?

Also, I'm not able to load the txt files in to input like this:

```
<input name="IP_data" load="text">
url: ".IP_data.txt"
</input>

<input name="Services_data" load="text">
url: ".IP_data.txt"
</input>

<input name="Rules_data" load="text">
url: ".IP_data.txt"
</input>
```

Any ideas or better example of loading and looking up data in ttd?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my answer for future generations ;)

For input problem the solutions is as follows:

```
<input name="IP_data">
url = "./data/"
extensions = ["txt"]
</input>

<group name="IPAddress.{{ IPName }}" input='IP_data'>
add IPAddress Name={{ IPName | WORD }} Address={{ IP }}
</group>
```

For lookups this works well:

```
<group name="IPAddress.{{ IPName }}" input='IP_data'>
add IPAddress Name={{ IPName | WORD }} Address={{ IP }}
</group>

<group name="Services.{{ PortName }}" input='Services_data'>
add ServiceTCPUDP Name={{ PortName | WORD }} Type={{ Protocol | default("Undefined") }} DestinationPorts={{ Ports | PHRASE | strip('"') }}
</group>

<group name="Rules" input='Rules_data'>
add IPRule SourceInterface={{ SrcInt }} DestinationInterface={{ DstInt }} SourceNetwork={{ SrcNet | WORD | lookup(group="IPAddress", add_field="SrcNet") }} DestinationNetwork={{ DstNet | WORD | lookup(group="IPAddress", add_field="DstNet") }} Service={{ Ports | WORD | lookup(group="Services", add_field="Ports") }} Action={{ Action }}
</group>
```